# SonarCloud requiring code coverage for files ignored with Istanbul

Tags: sonarqube, istanbul, sonarcloud

I have a JavaScript app where we generate a code coverage report using Istanbul and use SonarCloud for static analysis.

There are two ways we exclude code from the Istanbul. The first is to set exclusion paths. In `jest.config.js` we have this to exclude patterns:

```
"coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
  "source/legacy"
]
```

The second way is to use Istanbul ignore comments in source files like `/* istanbul ignore file */`. In either case the ignored file will not be part of the generated report file.

In our Sonar configuration we set it to use the generated `lcov.info` report file with the `sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths` property. However we then also need to set `sonar.coverage.exclusions` to exclude patterns like `source/legacy` because it is not treating the `lcov.info` report as the source of truth. This is acceptable but duplicates configuration, which is unfortunate. The real problem is that I cannot find any way to get Sonar to handle the files excluded with `/* istanbul ignore file */`.

Is there some way to make Sonar treat the `lcov.info` file as its source of truth, such that any file that is not included in the file is excluded from coverage?

Alternately, is there a way with Istanbul where I can make it list ignored files but say that they are ignored? Maybe that way Sonar will see that they are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for a solution, you unfortunately need to tell sonarqube to ignore this file explicitly. Not an ideal solution, but what I ended up with.

docs: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/

I put my filename in `sonar.coverage.exclusions`.

Answer (score 0):

What my organization ended up doing was making a policy to just not use istanbul ignore file comments, and instead ignore each function on a file. Also not ideal.